# How to speed up wasm (webassembly) loading times?

Tags: performance, scheme, webassembly

I created a small application using [chibi-scheme](http://synthcode.com/scheme/chibi/) wasm backend at [scheme-lang.com/cons](http://scheme-lang.com/cons/).

Here is the sizes of web assembly files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 amirouche amirouche 466K Jul  9 01:43 chibi.wasm
-rw-r--r--   1 amirouche amirouche 206K Jul  9 01:43 chibi.js
-rw-r--r--   1 amirouche amirouche 2.2M Jul  9 01:43 chibi.data
```

Here is chromium performance profile:

[image]

Loading times are not very great, how can I improve the situation?

Comment: For me it seems that WASM files of 3K size load almost instantaneous.

Comment: Show your analysis. I opened up dev console in that webpage and I don't think it's because of WASM.

Comment: You need to add more details about your analysis. and paste the code you tried.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My analysis is not very interesting. I had a look at the performance tab in firefox and chromium. It seems like the time is spent on wasm file processing. I think there is nothing I can do except make the interpreter compiled to wasm smaller.

Comment: Not really. If it supported compiling a Scheme program without `eval` it might become a much smaller thing, but you are using `eval` so the whole language needs to be available in runtime.